# Unused variable warning with static NSInteger, but not with NSString

Tags: objective-c, clang, unused-variables

After updating Xcode to version 5.1, I had a warning that told me I had defined a constant that I wasn't using. Its definition looked like this:

```
static NSInteger const ABCMyInteger = 3;
```

I was happy to see that it got marked, because I thought this meant that the compiler was now able to check for unused constants in addition local to variables.

I refactored some more, making three `NSString` constants obsolete. All three were defined very similarly to the `NSInteger` from above:

```
static NSString *const ABCMyString = @"ABCMyString";
```

To my surprise, however, these do not get marked as "unused", though I know for sure that they aren't used anymore.

Can someone explain why an `NSInteger` does get noticed by the compiler as unused, but an `NSString` does not?

Comment: The only difference I can spot is that NSInteger is a primitive data type, whereas NSString is a class. Maybe (but surprisingly) the compiler generate warnings for primitive types only.  I suggest you to try with other types (float, char, NSArray, UIView) to verify if I am right or not (I haven't updated to 5.1 yet, so I can't try myself).

Comment: @Antonio: Looks like you're right, it only works for primitives. `float` triggered it, `NSArray` did not. My question still remains: why is the compiler not able to do this with objects?

Comment: As a side note, other IDEs (at least AppCode) are able to warn about unused NSString constants, but they rely on some additional code inspection, not the compiler warnings

Comment: Also, if you put `static NSString *const ABCMyString = @"ABCMyString";`
inside a method (that is, not in a global scope) XCode actually warns you about "unused variable" :) interesting

Comment: Adding an `extern static NSInteger const ABCMyInteger;` in an H file should remove the warning.

Comment: @LeoNatan: That gives me "Cannot combine with previous 'extern' declaration'. That would also make the constant public which is not always desirable.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets I may have messed up the syntax, but it's just the idea. But yes, my post is about public constants (not really related to your question). Why the compiler does not warn about unused objects is good question. Likely a bug or a known limitation.

Comment: Looks like the CLANG folks already know this is a limitation.  [rdar://10777111](https://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=161291)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primitive variable is just a memory block allocated in a static memory part and initialized by the compiler. The string object, however, is a variable initialized at runtime (in startup, probably), so the compiler adds an implicit call to the constructor and *uses* the variable as a parameter for that call. So the variable is being used.

The `_unused` item of the structure is IMHO not a directive, but just a member variable, probably it is added for better alignment (fills the object size to a round size).

Answer (score 1):

The definition of an `NSString` literal at compile time rely on the use of the `NSSimpleCString` meta class.
This class looks something like this:

```
@interface NSSimpleCString : NSString {
@package
    char *bytes;
    int numBytes;
#if __LP64__
    int _unused;
#endif
}
@end

@interface NSConstantString : NSSimpleCString
@end
```

The addition of the `_unused` flag make me believe that further down the implementation of `NSSimpleCString` the code will instruct the compiler to silence those warnings with `__unused`.
You can try yourself by prepending your integer or float constant with `__unused` like:

```
__unused static const NSInteger ABCMyInteger = 3;
```

For a more in depth explanation read [the article on literals](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-06-22-objective-c-literals.html) by Mike Ash

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! For some reason, the `__unused` directive is implicitly used on `NSConstantString` (or one of its subclasses). The `_unused` ivar may have to do with it, but to me it's unclear how it plays a role in this situation, especially since it depends on a 64-bit architecture, and the warning is also there when I build for 32-bit only.

Comment: You are right I should have made more that `_unused` is not the compiler flag, but it is flag likely to trigger it dipper in the code implementation of `NSSimpleCString` and so likely `NSConstantString`

Comment: Quite possibly. I would accept that, if it wasn't conditionally compiled with `__LP64__`. That instance variable doesn't exist on 32-bit platforms (unless it is defined privately there, but I don't see why they would do that), but the compiler doesn't give the warning on 32-bit either.

Comment: I am not 100% sure of this, but I think the hardware you chose for your target doesn't count, what counts is the precompiler defines. There are several reports around about weird responses of the use of `__LP64__` (first comment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861046/how-to-determine-if-compiling-for-64-bit-ios-in-xcode).
Also if you try to check for the precompiler #define on your machine with `cpp -dM /dev/null |grep __LP64__` you will see that `__LP64__` is there no matter what.